# problem with custom list view that crashes my app

Tags: android, image, listview, view

I'm trying to make on item click listener but when I do it the app crashes and I don't know why here's the code I'm using .. I tried some codes like start activity and start activity for result but nothing it crashes all the time please help

```
package com.embid2.myapplication;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.annotation.Nullable;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    ListView listView;
    String[] menutitles;
    int[] imges={R.drawable.iconfinder_food__dish__kitchen__3653390,R.drawable.iconfinder_pages_1118205,R.drawable.iconfinder_special_price_5418372};
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Resources res =getResources();
        menutitles=res.getStringArray(R.array.titles);
        listView=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        myadapter myadapter=new myadapter(this,menutitles,imges);
        listView.setAdapter(myadapter);

    }
}

class myadapter extends ArrayAdapter<String>
{
    Context context;
    int[] imges;
    String[] titles;
    myadapter(Context c,String[]titles,int[] imges)
    {
        super(c,R.layout.single_row,R.id.text,titles);
        this.context=c;
        this.imges=imges;
        this.titles=titles;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, @Nullable View convertView, @NonNull ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater= (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.single_row,parent,false);
        ImageView myimage =(ImageView)row.findViewById(R.id.image);
        TextView mytitle=(TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.text);
        myimage.setImageResource(imges[position]);
        mytitle.setText(titles[position]);
        return row;
    }
}
```

Comment: please post the stacktrace, thanks

Answer (score 0):

App crash because there is not any method to handle on click.

In your getView method you can set click listener like

```
myImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            //do some stuff
        }
    });
```

Comment: Then add recycler view  and remove list view . Create adapter for recycler view and then set click listener on image.